# How to create an FParsec parser that checks if the string is contained within an array?

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I am trying to create a parser that recognizes the names of predefined functions in contrast to general/random string literals.

I am looking to create a parser starting with the following code as the function defintion: `let pArray (arr:'a[]) :Parser<'a> =`... but I am unsure how to continue.

In short, I think I need to somehow get the `CharStream` (as a string) out of the `Parser<'a>` type and compare this with what is contained in the array. Just not sure how to achieve that?

The other alternative is to create an array of string parsers - one for each element of the array and apply/combine them with the alternative combinator `<|>` into a single parser. This seems (no evidence) heavy-handed though given that I have approx 400 distinct functions. Is it OK to create a parser with this many alternatives or will performance come under undue pressure?

I have searched in the FParsec user guide but couldn't find something matching this scenario - am I on the right path or is this NOT the way I should be solving this problem?

Comment: This may be largely related (or even a duplicate) of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763942/fparsec-identifiers-vs-keywords). You may need to provide with some code and sample input to explain your needs.