# How to add a condition that a parsed number must satisfy in FParsec?

Tags: f#, fparsec

I am trying to parse an int32 with FParsec but have an additional restriction that the number must be less than some maximum value. Is their a way to perform this without writing my own custom parser (as below) and/or is my custom parser (below) the appropriate way of achieving the requirements.

I ask because most of the built-in library functions seem to revolve around a **char** satisfying certain predicates and not any other type.

```
let pRow: Parser<int> = 
   let error = messageError ("int parsed larger than maxRows")
   let mutable res = Reply(Error, error)
   fun stream ->
      let reply = pint32 stream
      if reply.Status = Ok && reply.Result <= 1000000 then
         res <- reply
      res
```

## UPDATE

Below is an attempt at a more fitting FParsec solution based on the direction given in the comment below:

```
let pRow2: Parser<int> = 
   pint32 >>= (fun x -> if x <= 1048576 then (preturn x) else fail "int parsed larger than maxRows")
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Can demonstrate later but check out `bind` + `fail`

Comment: @FuleSnabel thanks, I will check them out but please do answer with a sample - will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've done an excellent research and almost answered your own question.

Generally, there are two approaches:

1. *Unconditionally* parse out an `int` and let the further code to check it for validity;
2. Use a *guard rule* bound to the parser. In this case `(>>=)` is the right tool;

In order to make a good choice, ask yourself whether an integer that *failed* to pass the guard rule has to "give another chance" by triggering **another parser**?

Here's what I mean. Usually, in real-life projects, parsers are combined in some chains. If one parser fails, the following one is attempted. For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9763942/974789), some programming language is parsed, so it needs something like:

```
let pContent =
    pLineComment <|> pOperator <|> pNumeral <|> pKeyword <|> pIdentifier
```

Theoretically, your DSL may need to differentiate a "small int value" from another type:

```
/// The resulting type, or DSL
type Output =
    | SmallValue of int
    | LargeValueAndString of int * string
    | Comment of string

let pSmallValue =
    pint32 >>= (fun x -> if x <= 1048576 then (preturn x) else fail "int parsed larger than maxRows")
    |>> SmallValue
let pLargeValueAndString =
    pint32 .>> ws .>>. (manyTill ws)
    |>> LargeValueAndString
let pComment =
    manyTill ws
    |>> Comment

let pCombined =
    [ pSmallValue; pLargeValueAndString; pComment]
    |> List.map attempt // each parser is optional
    |> choice // on each iteration, one of the parsers must succeed
    |> many // a loop
```

Built this way, `pCombined` will return:

- `"42 ABC"` gets parsed as `[ SmallValue 42 ; Comment "ABC" ]`
- `"1234567 ABC"` gets parsed as `[ LargeValueAndString(1234567, "ABC") ]`

As we see, the guard rule impacts how the parsers are applied, so the guard rule has to be within the parsing process.

If, however, you don't need such complication (e.g., an `int` is parsed **unconditionally**), your first snippet is just fine.