# Parse using a list of strings in FParsec

Tags: fparsec

I am checking for reserved words using something like this:

```
let astr s = attempt (pstringCI s)
let reservedWord = astr "text" <|> astr "date" // etc.
```

Is it possible to create a parser performs the same check but which takes an array of the reserved words as a parameter?  Something like:

```
newReservedWordParser "something" ["text"; "date"; ...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [`choice`](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.choice)? It takes a `seq` as parameter.

You can use it like so:

```ml
let reservedWords = [
    "word1"
    "word2"
]

let parseReservedWord = reservedWords |> List.map pstringCI |> choice
```

I'm doing something similar in my project [here](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/LtGt/blob/40fac5e4084e840ce9e778fe42565bb9436e48a1/LtGt/HtmlParsing.fs#L104-L114)

Comment: Oh, wow - how simple is that?  You can just pipe it to choice!!!  Thank you, @Tyrrz :)

Answer (score 0):

Having stumbled across the answer from @bytebuster [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13951778/2608), this can be done like so (not sure I need this any longer though!):

```
let reservedWord (reservedWords: string list) = 
    (many1 letter |>> System.String.Concat) >>= 
    fun x -> 
        if List.contains x reservedWords then preturn x 
        else fail "not a reserved word"
```

LINQPad share [here](http://share.linqpad.net/iofjhs.linq).

FParsec documentation about `>>=` is [here](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/applying-parsers-in-sequence.html).